# Qt how can I select the word under the mouse in a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` and i want to highlight the actual word under the current mouse pointer
so how can I find this word?

```
void LogItemDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
    const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
    const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString text = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    // so how can i find the word under the mousepointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    QString text = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    if(option.state & QStyle::State_MouseOver)
    {
        painter->setPen(Qt::blue);
        painter->drawText(option.rect,text);
    }
    else
    {
        QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,option,index);
    }
```

Also you can try:

```
painter->drawText(option.rect.adjusted(3, 7, 0, 0),txt);
```

for better visual representation.

But I can predict that this will not work. Why? You should allow mouse tracking, so just add:

```
ui->tableView->setMouseTracking(true);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new LogItemDelegate);
```

Comment: mhh i think this will highlight the whole text not only the word under
and also i would like have the text self for further use

Comment: @helmi yes, it will highlight whole text in cell. There is no way to do it easy and not painful for system. I think that searching of this word(if there is possibility to do this at all) will make your app very expensive for system. All time app will check every mouse moving and do complex calculation to get this word, so try to use my answer. If someone post here full solution I definitely delete my answer. But now I think that my approach is the most suitable.

Comment: thanks but thats not usebale for me so i need real the word maybe only when i click on it that would be mor cpu friendly